# How do I know if a class is a wrapper for an unmanaged resource

Tags: c#

How do I know if a class in C# is unmanaged, so that if I use it in a self defined class I know whether I have to implement the IDisposable interface?

If I get this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.idisposable.aspx) on the MSDN network right, I always have to implement the IDisposible interface when I use an unmanaged resource.

So I've created a little example that you can find below:

```
class TestClass
{
    private StreamReader reader;

    public UsingTestClass()
    {
        reader = File.OpenText("C:\\temp\\test.txt");

        string s;
        while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s = reader.ReadLine()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

    }
}
```

The following [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) says for example that File is an unamanged ressource, which is also used in my test class. So how can I see, that this class is unamanged?
The compiler and ReSharper didn't complain anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is the best practice to act in sich cases?Especially of you use third party libraries?

Comment: Everything that implements IDisposable should be disposed when You are done with it.

Comment: Code analysis should pick this up, as you have have a class member which implements IDisposable, but yet you don't dispose it nor implement IDisposable yourself.

Comment: `StreamReader` is not an unmanaged resource itself, but it wraps one, and therefore it implements `IDisposable`. Anything that implements `IDisposable` should be disposed. Other than that, you don't have to worry about unmanaged resources unless you're using Windows API calls via PInvoke (because anything that wraps resources allocated that way should implement IDisposable).

Comment: You need to read very carefully here, man. The article says that `File` **accesses** unmanaged resources. It doesn't say that `File` is an unmanaged resource. This is a big difference to a C# developer.

Comment: Visual Studio has Analyse menu item that will detect you doing this incorrectly. Or look to see if the class implements IDisposable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How do I know if a class in C# is unmanaged

That gets you off on the wrong track right away, **all** classes in C# are managed.  The language has no support for using unmanaged classes at all.  None of the .NET languages do, except one: C++/CLI.  Which is a rather untypical language specifically designed to help a programmer use a native C++ class.  Usage of that language is specialized and not relevant to this question.

What matters is whether the managed class is a **wrapper** for an unmanaged resource.  A wrapper is the kind of class that has a purely managed interface but that *internally* uses an unmanaged resource, usually through pinvoke with the [DllImport] attribute.  The resource is almost always represented with an `IntPtr`.  An unmanaged handle or pointer.

Such a wrapper needs a finalizer to ensure that the unmanaged resource is always released.  If that doesn't happen then you have a *leak*, the kind of bug that (eventually) crashes a program when the operating system gets upset about a program using too many resources.

And since it has a finalizer, it also implements IDisposable.  Allowing a program to release the unmanaged resource early, before the GC gets around to calling the finalizer.  Using the Dispose() method or the *using* statement is optional, the finalizer is good enough to ensure the job gets done.

But sometimes the finalizer isn't good enough because a program doesn't generate garbage quickly enough and then it is pretty important that you help.  You can't really know whether you have to help so most .NET programmers always do.  And a subset never does and have not ever noticed a problem in years of programming.  We do eventually hear from them at SO :)

---

Your example of a StreamReader is a good one to get to the next step.  StreamReader does not actually wrap an unmanaged resource.  All of its code is written in C# and it does not have any pinvoke, there's not an unmanaged bone in its body.  And does therefore *not* have a finalizer.  But still has a Dispose() method.

StreamReader got "infected".  It is also a wrapper class but for a Stream, not an IntPtr.  A purely managed abstract .NET type, itself a wrapper.  Which implements IDisposable, now StreamReader *has* to implement it as well.  So when you call the StreamReader's Dispose() method then the Stream.Dispose() method can run.

This is *layering* at work, there is a hierarchy of classes.  StreamReader wraps Stream which wraps FileStream which wraps SafeFileHandle which *actually* wraps the IntPtr.  Only SafeFileHandle has a finalizer.

---

Understanding the layering is where everybody gives up, that requires pretty deep insight into the way these .NET classes are structured.  You can get there but it takes years.  There are three basic shortcuts:

- Have an understanding of how an operating system works.  Gives you the insight that a file is an operating system resource, bet your booty that when you use a file there is a need to dispose or close it.
- Use the MSDN library article for the class you use.  When you see it has a Dispose() method then there almost always is a good reason to use it.  Sometimes there is not but you'll never be wrong when you use it anyway.
- Get in trouble, make all the mistakes that every programmer needs to make, use SO or a memory profiler to find out what you did wrong.  Nothing ever wrong with learning how to do it right.

Comment: Summary: So if we use `using` or `Dispose()` in every class, that implements `IDisposable` we are always safe? Are there cases, where we do not want to call `Dispose()` on `IDisposable`?

Comment: I hate summaries, try to understand all the words.  If I could have used less then I would have.  Not "always safe", don't dispose an object that's in use elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer.